# Magento 2 - add simple product programstically to specific web site

Tags: magento2

1. My Store has 3 web sites: UK (default), USA, GER.
2. In my module, I'm adding product programatically to specific web site
3. Apart from the specified country, the Product is also always added to default web site.

**EXAMPLE:**

When I add product to USA, it is automatically being added to UK too.

How do I prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

may be you can add website after the product has been saved.

Just use instances of the Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductWebsiteLinkInterface and Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductWebsiteLinkRepositoryInterface repository with code similar to the below:

```
...

$mageProduct = $this->productRepository->save($mageProduct, true);

// Instance of ProductWebsiteLinkInterface
$siteLink = $this->productWebsiteLink;
$siteLink->setSku($mageProduct->getSku());
$siteLink->setWebsiteId(1);

// Instance of ProductWebsiteLinkRepositoryInterface
$websiteLinkRepo = $this->productWebsiteLinkRepository;
$websiteLinkRepo->save($siteLink);
```

Please try this and let me know if you need any further help.

Thanks

Comment: Please let me know if this solution helps you and also let me know if you need any other help as well.